# Sails.js / Waterline and TypeScript - Calling One Attribute Method from Another

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sails.js

I have a Sails.js / Waterline ORM modle. It has several attribute methods defined. However, I am having difficulty calling one attribute method from another; I am receiving an error that attribute method is "not a function". I thought using "this" would work:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        cartID: {
            type: "string",
            defaultsTo: function() {
                return uuidv4();
            }
        },

        subTotal: {
            type: "float",
            defaultsTo: 0
        },

        shipping: {
            type: "float",
            defaultsTo: 0
        },

        discount: {
            type: "float",
            defaultsTo: 0
        },

        total: {
            type: "float",
            defaultsTo: 0
        },

        cartItems: {
            collection: "cartitem",
            via: "cart"
        },

        updateCart: () => {
            this.discount = 0;
            this.shipping = this.calcShipping();
            this.total = this.calcTotal();
            this.subTotal = this.calcSubTotal();

        },

        calcSubTotal: (): number => {
            let total: number = 0;
            for (let i: number = 0; i <= this.cartItems.length; i++) {
                total += (this.cartItems[i].listing.price * this.cartItems[i].quantity);
            }

            return total;
        },

        returnTransactionJSON: () => {
            return JSON.stringify({
                intent: "sale",
                payer: {
                    payment_method: "paypal"
                },
                redirect_urls: {
                    return_url: "Checkout/Confirmation",
                    cancel_url: "Checkout/Cancel"
                },
                transactions: [{
                    amount: {
                        total: this.total,
                        currency: "USD"
                    },
                    description: "Order from Hawthorne Acres."
                }]
            });
        },



        calcTotal: (): number => {
            return this.subTotal + this.shipping - this.discount;
        },

        calcDiscounts: (): number => {
            let discount: number = 0;
            if (this.cartItems.length >= 6) {
                let lowestPrice: number = this.cartItems[0].price;
                for (let i: number = 0; i <= this.cartItems.length; i++) {
                    if (this.cartItems[i].listing.price < lowestPrice) {
                        lowestPrice == this.cartItems[i];
                    }
                }

                discount = (Math.floor(this.cartItems.length / 6) * -lowestPrice);

            }

            return discount;
        },
        calcShipping: (): number => {
            let shipping: number = 0;
            switch (this.cartItems.length) {
                case 1:
                    shipping = 3.49;
                case 2:
                    shipping = 4.49;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    shipping = 5.99;
                case 6:
                    shipping = 6.49;
            }
            return shipping;
        }


    }

}
```

However, I receive the following error when "updateCart" is called:

```
    TypeError: _this.calcShipping is not a function
    at child.updateCart (/home/kelly/workspace/Hawthorne-Acres/api/models/Cart.ts:108:34)
    at Cart.findOne.exec (/home/kelly/workspace/Hawthorne-Acres/api/controllers/CheckoutController.js:54:22)
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normaliz
e.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.j
s:324:18)
    at success (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.j
s:33:31)
    at _switch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:
58:28)
    at returnResults (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic
.js:179:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:86:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:83:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_module
s/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/as
ync/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:436:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:574:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_module
s/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/as
ync/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at _buildChildOpts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/ope
rations.js:464:9)
    at _execChildOpts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/oper
ations.js:432:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:81:10
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
```

If I try remove the "this" keyword (for example this.shipping = calcShipping();), the code will not even compile; because the function "cannot be found".

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrow functions.

However Sails binds those functions to the instance of you class does not respect `this`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions